# How to display everything from an object including nested objects and arrays?

Tags: javascript

I have an object which have nested objects and an array. I'm trying to `console.log` all the data including the data inside the nested object but failing to do so. The result I'm getting shows all the data except the ones which are objects. I get `[Object object]` instead of those. What I want is to display everything in the console in a format which is not an object or JSON(like the result below, except I want to display the values of f and g as well).

This is the object:

```
let data = { 
    a: 'Tesla',
    b: 'Mclaren',
    c: 'Ferrari',
    d: 'Lamborghini',
    e: 'Lotus',
    'f':{ 
        name: 'John',
        'e-mail': 'xyz@example.com',
        phone: '+12345678',
        country: 'USA',
        car: 'Toyota Prius' 
    },
    'g':{ 
        name: 'Sophie',
        'e-mail': 'xyz@example.com',
        phone: '+12345678',
        country: 'UK',
        car: 'Nissan Bluebird' 
    },
    h: 'Volkswagen',
    i: 'Bugatti',
    j:[ 
        '% mileage',
        '% top speed',
        '% suspension',
        '% navigation',
        '% horsepower',
        '% 0-60s' 
    ] 
}
```

This is the code I tried:

```
for(var key in data){
    console.log(key + " : " + data[key]);
}
```

This is the result I'm getting:

```
a : Tesla
b : Mclaren
c : Ferrari
d : Lamborghini
e : Lotus
f : [object Object]
g : [object Object]
h : Volkswagen
i : Bugatti
j : % mileage,% top speed,% suspension,% navigation,% horsepower,% 0-60s
```

Comment: You're concatenating what ever is stored in `data[key]` with a string. For an object this will call `.toString()` which will return `"[object Object]"`. Just remove the concatenation... -> `console.log(key, data[key])`

Comment: Hey I just tried that. But the output of f and g shows in object formats. I mean with brackets.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
let data = { 
    a: 'Tesla',
    b: 'Mclaren',
    c: 'Ferrari',
    d: 'Lamborghini',
    e: 'Lotus',
    'f':{ 
        name: 'John',
        'e-mail': 'xyz@example.com',
        phone: '+12345678',
        country: 'USA',
        car: 'Toyota Prius' 
    },
    'g':{ 
        name: 'Sophie',
        'e-mail': 'xyz@example.com',
        phone: '+12345678',
        country: 'UK',
        car: 'Nissan Bluebird' 
    },
    h: 'Volkswagen',
    i: 'Bugatti',
    j:[ 
        '% mileage',
        '% top speed',
        '% suspension',
        '% navigation',
        '% horsepower',
        '% 0-60s' 
    ] 
}

for(var key in data){
    console.log(key + ": ", data[key]);
}
```

Comment: Hey, sadly no. The output format should look like the one I posted in OP. Is that possible? Thanks a lot though for the code.

Comment: I see, okay, take a look at my code now. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Hey, it is close. Is it possible to get rid of the object syntaxes of f, g and j? I want to display it simple like a, b, c, etc

Comment: You want the curly-braces to disappear, is that what you mean? :/

Comment: I'm afraid so, you could try stringifying the object, parsing it yourself etc. but that seems like a lot of work :/ Maybe someone else knows. Hope you work it out, and thanks for the solution thing :)

Answer (score 1):

[`console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)))`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log):

Chrome and Firefox at least will log a *reference* to an object if you just `console.log(obj)`. `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))` is going to convert your object to JSON which isn't an object. `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)))` will convert the JSON back to an object as a separate, isolated reference that will not change.

```js
let data = { 
    a: 'Tesla',
    b: 'Mclaren',
    c: 'Ferrari',
    d: 'Lamborghini',
    e: 'Lotus',
    'f':{ 
        name: 'John',
        'e-mail': 'xyz@example.com',
        phone: '+12345678',
        country: 'USA',
        car: 'Toyota Prius' 
    },
    'g':{ 
        name: 'Sophie',
        'e-mail': 'xyz@example.com',
        phone: '+12345678',
        country: 'UK',
        car: 'Nissan Bluebird' 
    },
    h: 'Volkswagen',
    i: 'Bugatti',
    j:[ 
        '% mileage',
        '% top speed',
        '% suspension',
        '% navigation',
        '% horsepower',
        '% 0-60s' 
    ] 
};

console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)));
```

Comment: Care to explain why converting an object to JSON to then parse it back into an object and then pass it to `console.log()` is the "answer"? o.O `console.log(data)` does exactly the same...

Comment: @Andreas logging an object to the console displays a reference to the object, so if you change the object downstream, the entry in the console is also changed. This isn't great for debugging purposes, since normally you want to see a snapshot of it at the time you logged to the console. If you stringify and then parse it, it becomes its own separate object instance.

Comment: @CrayonViolent `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` (or with some formatting) would be enough for this case.

Comment: Hi. Isn't it possible to output the data without brackets and parentheses? I was thinking to display it the way I'm getting the result in the OP.

Comment: "What I want is to display everything in the console." You didn't specify any special formatting needs.

Comment: @Andreas If you want a static,unformatted string, or do extra work to make it into some other format you prefer (as OP seems to want to do), then sure...

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

OR

```
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Hey, I tried those. The output comes in JSON or object format which I dont want. I want a clean format with no brackets or quotations. Exactly like the result in the OP, except I want to display the properties and values in f and g as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the node environment, you can use the inspect method from the util module: https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_showhidden_depth_colors

```
const util = require('util');
console.log(util.inspect(bigObject, false, null, true)) ;
```

You can also have it log with colours, by setting the last argument to true like the above!

If you are in the browser environment, you can still use the util module, but you will have to use a bundler like webpack or browserify.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the output format `console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))` should work fine

Comment: Hey output format should look like the one I posted in OP. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you iterate through an object that contains object instance then it will be logged as reference.If you want to iterate to throw the object in object use typeof while iterating.If it is object then iterate through the inner object.

Comment: Hey. Can you provide a working code? I'm new at this mate.